# How to pull data from web based on input in a cell

Tags: excel

So, What I'm looking to do is pull data from a website based on information in another cell. So for example, I'd like to pull information from airnav.com specifically information about certain airports such as control tower frequencies. In order to find the frequencies, you go to Airports then type in the airport code (example: "KRNT" for Renton airport in Washington).

Example: Cell A1 has "KRNT" put into it, excel then pulls the airport frequency automatically into cell B2.

So how would I get excel to look at a cell and search for the info for that specific airport code and pull it into another cell? I'm assuming this is possible but I'm not entirely sure.

Note, I am fairly proficient with excel but by no means an advanced user.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

Cant you simply have 2 sheets.

Sheet one column A being the input cell and on sheet 2 column A having the different airport codes and column B the formula for pulling external web data.

Then in column B of sheet 1 placing this formula to match the input of column A on sheet 1 and 2 and import the data in column B of sheet 1 from column B sheet 2..

- Sheet 1 - Column A (input field) Column B (place formula below)
- Sheet 2 - Column A (airport codes) Column B (data pulled for said airport)

---

```
=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!A2,Sheet2!A:B,2)
```

Comment: I understand how to do that, but I am wondering if there is a way to have excel look at one cell and use that to search for the correct data. So if I decided to change the data in the initial cell, it would then change the data in the second cell automatically.

Comment: I could, but that would involve pulling data from THOUSANDS of airports manually. Which kind of defeats the purpose of automation :P I do appreciate your help though!

Answer (score 0):

This does what you want.
It doesn't get pretty but that is how excel works when it comes to "get from web".

You need to open VBA editor and dubble click on Sheet1 in the project window.
Then paste the following code.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Target.Worksheet.Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then

------------------------------------

        With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
            "URL;http://airnav.com/airport/" & Range("A1").Value, Destination:=Range("$B$1")) ' <--- This line must be as I wrote it. 
            .FieldNames = True
            .RowNumbers = False
            .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
            .PreserveFormatting = False
            .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
            .BackgroundQuery = True
            .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells  '<--- And this one.
            .SavePassword = False
            .SaveData = True
            .AdjustColumnWidth = True
            .RefreshPeriod = 0
            .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
            .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
            .WebTables = "6,7,8,9,32,33,34,35,36,37"
            .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
            .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
            .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
            .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
            .WebDisableRedirections = False
            .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        End With
----------------------------------        
    End If
End Sub
```

Save the file as a macroactivated workbook and type a airport in A1 and press Enter.

As I said... It's not pretty...

I have uploaded the file here: https://expirebox.com/download/dfbae2fbc4410bbaf64d068443ac84bf.html
I have never used this site before, not sure how it works.

Comment: This is freaking awesome! Is there by chance any way to specify which info it pulls in? I realize this may get complicated, but I'm hoping to just pull certain parts of the webpage such as the control tower frequency and one or two other sections...

Comment: Yes there is... But honestly I think you can do it better than me. I don't know what you need. Do you have the developer tab in Excel ribbon? If not, google how to enable it. Then record a macro of you "get from web", and copy paste that code to my code above. Note there is two lines that you need to keep the way I wrote them. I will mark them in my answer above.

Comment: No problem. If you run in to problems just write a comment here and I will try to help you.

Comment: Actually one more question. Where exactly would I place in the code from the Macro? before, after, in?

Comment: The two lines in the code above shows what code you need to edit when you have recorded a new macro. Unless you have clicked on anything else the code you get recorded will look almost the same as my code between the two lines (except the two lines I marked out earlier)